# raspberry pi websocket client program hangs when connected to raspberry pi access point

Tags: c, websocket, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4

I have a simple websocket program where a server and client exchange a message and then exit, taken from a geeks for geeks tutorial:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/

server.c:

```
// Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8080 
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 
       
    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
       
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, 
                                                  &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 
       
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                                 sizeof(address))<0) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

client.c:

```
// Client side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8080 
   
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    printf("$");
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    printf("@");
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
    printf("#");
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
       
    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    //CURRENT IP IS RPI4 IP
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.12", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
    { 
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
   
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    }
    printf("!\n");
    send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

My raspberry pi 4 is the server and my raspberry pi 3 is the client.  On my normal home wifi network this program executes exactly as expected.

However I have turned my RPI4 into a standalone wifi access point using this tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

When I connect the RPI3 client to the RPI4 network, and run the server and then the client program it hangs and seems like it isn't even running the first line of code and printing the "$", (this may not be the case as the assembler may move the first print statement somewhere else in execution).

I'm assuming this isn't a problem with my either of my programs but a problem with either the RPI4 access point or the RPI3's connection to the access point, but I know very little about networking.  Can someone help me troubleshoot and pinpoint what the problem is?

Comment: stdout is line buffered. That is, `printf("$")` will not output until a newline or an `fflush(stdout);` is called. Call `fflush` to aid your debugging. And there is no need to guess at what the code is doing. Use a debugger to give you the exact stack trace of what the program is doing.

Comment: Thank you I will do that and update the question if need be.